# No ability to add a WCF web service to a .NET 6.0 VB.NET Winforms app

Tags: wcf, .net-core

[image]I can't seem to add a WCF web service to a Winforms .NET 6 application  in VS2022. All I see is "Connected Services" and the ability to add a "Service Dependency".

I have included these namespaces:

```
System.ServiceModel.Http
System.ServiceModel.NetTcp
System.ServiceModel.Primatives
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: See other SO questions on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177047/wcf-client-migration-to-net-6

Answer (score 2):

1.Open VS and search for **WCF Connected Service** in the Extensions -Manager Extensions.

2.Open **Connected Service**. At this point, the **Service Reference will appear**.
[image]

3.Select **WCF Web Service**, and then choose Next.

This brings up the Add new **WCF Web Service service reference wizard**.

[image]

Comment: The issue is that I dont see the lower half of the "Add new WCF .." form. The "Add Service Ref" portion is missing.

Comment: First, **WCF Service Reference** can be added directly in **the Connected Service**, which is implemented through the **WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool**. Here is its introductory document: [Use the WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide). It mentioned above that it only works with C# etc. This is my mistake.

Comment: My suggestion is to convert WCF into WSDL files and convert them into VB code through **Svcutil .exe**.